# Moto G X Play 3rd generation doesn't detect SD but Windows 10 does

Tags: sd-card

Weird :

My phone suddently stopped being detected by my phone.

So, I hard formatted it in windows, in FAT32.

It didn't work, but windows detect it well, I have no problem to read / copy files in it.

I tried my SD in another phone, and it works.

I tried a new SD in my phone and it works.

I don't really know what to do, it is a 32GB SD, so I would like to keep it.

Any idea????

Comment: Was your SD set as adoptable storage? https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/answers/prod_answer_detail/a_id/105572/p/30,6720,9390

Comment: in could be, but how should I restore my previous state??? In the doc you sent me,  it says: Settings > Storage > select SD card ... but as my phone doesnt detect SD, I have no : SD card option

Comment: When I insert another 4GB SD Card, I can see the SD and can convert it to Internal, but not with mine as phone can't see it

Comment: Try formatting it in extFAT and put it again in the phone.

Comment: Already triedit :(

Comment: You said the formatting didn't work? Try with Diskpart (diskpart.exe).

Comment: I just tried it.... Didn't work neither :(

Comment: damaged SD card, sorry

Comment: but if it were damaged, I couldn't use it in another phone / windows

Comment: The weird part. I thought somehow it was read-only but you say you write data on it...

Comment: Yep. I just switched it to my girlfriend phone and it s working like a charm

Comment: Did you try formatting it with her phone?

Comment: Yep did it but no results